# Google auto-placed ads is doing harm to my CLS score, how can I improve this?

Tags: adsense, cumulative-layout-shift

Recently I have noticed that Google auto placed ads (in AdSense) have done quite negative impact on my CLS performance.

Is there any way I can fix it? I don't even know where I can see these kind of ads on my pages. Is there any way I can turn it on for debug?

[image: auto-placed ads CLS penalty]